# Non Renewing Subscription - Restore

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase, itunes, non-renewing-subscription

To restore my InAppPurchase for Non-Renewing Subscription type,  I have implemented my server to handle this.

But not some times during purchase iTunes ask users to verify their card details,

In this case it sends app in background and present iTunes to verify the account and card details and after verification it again ask to make payment for purchase and app remains in background.

In this case how can i check that user payed for which product and is that payment was successful or not.

I use "restoreCompletedTransactions" to restore in which i receive Zero transactions.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I got this after long time of rnd.

Always add TransactionObserver in application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: and remove this observer in applicationWillTerminate:

And this transaction observer always observe your default Payment queue and and transactions which can be in any state and one more "IMPORTANT POINT"  is that a transaction always remain in your default transaction queue until you finish that transaction by SKPaymentQueue method "finishTransaction:transaction".

And for my question TransactionObserver always calls its delegate methods "paymentQueue:updatedTransactions:" when we come back to our app after the account verification.